# Making a scheduler in c++

Tags: c++

Hello my c++ Homework is to make a scheduler but it does not work how I want it to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct schedule{
    char date[12];
    
    char time[6];
    
    int importance;
    
    char name[128];
    
    char content[128];
};

void showSchedule(struct schedule *sch, unsigned long long num){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
    int j;
        for(j = 0; j < 12; j++){
            printf("%c",(sch+i)->date[j]);
    
            if(j==3||j==5||j==7){
                printf(".");
            }
        }
    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++){
    
            printf("%c",(sch+i)->time[j]);
            
            if(j==1) printf(":");
        }
        printf("%d ",(sch)->importance);
        printf("%s ",(sch)->name);
        printf("%s\n",(sch)->content);
    }
}

int main(){
       
      
    unsigned long long num;
           
    scanf("%ull",&num);
        
    struct schedule *sch;
         
    sch = (struct schedule *)malloc(num * sizeof(struct schedule));
          
    int i;
            
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
             
        scanf("%s",(sch+i)->date);
              
        scanf("%s",(sch+i)->time);
             
        scanf("%d",&(sch+i)->importance);
             
        scanf("%s",(sch+i)->name);
           
        scanf("%s",(sch+i)->content);
    }
     showSchedule(sch, num);
    free(sch);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code but I need to input the number of the schedule numbers then 'Date(yyyyMMdd) Time(hhmm) Importance Title Content' in this format.
for example if I input

```
2
20170302 0900 8 classes listentoclasses
20170303 1330 7 tasks Codingtask
```

after the code has finished running the output should be

```
2017.03.02. 09:00 8 classes listentoclasses
2017.03.03. 13:30 7 tasks Codingtask
```

But when I run the script

```
2017.03.02. 
 09:00 S8 classes listentoclasses
2017.03.03. gra13:30 e8 classes listentoclasses
```

I get this output

Can I get any help?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `+i` on this and the next two: `printf("%d ",(sch)->importance);`

Comment: If you're supposed to write a program in C++, why are you writing C code?

Comment: Don't forget to check the return code from `scanf` to make sure you got all the tokens you asked for..

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm This code is valid (I mean compilable) C++ code. This will be correct answer after fixing bugs. I don't know whether the grade will be low for not using C++ specific features.

Comment: i deleted my bad answer lol. But in short, when you"re confronted with dates it's preferable to use more standard tools than just char[12], like Boost::date for example. It will help you making sure than the date is actually valid (35.77.2020 is not a valid date), and also helping a lot with formating. See for example [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.io_tutorial) how date IO can be done.

Answer (score 1):

- You are invoking *undefined behavior* by passing `scanf()` data having wrong type at the line `scanf("%ull",&num);`: `%u` expects `unsigned int*`, but `&num` is `unsigned long long`. You should use `%llu` instead of `%ull`.
- You are running too much iterations to print the date and time and invoking *undefined behavior* by using values allocated via `malloc()` and uninitialized, which are indeterminate.
- You forgot to print spaces between the date and the time, and the time and the importance.
- You are repeatedly printing `importance`, `name` and `content` of the first element.
- Some lines in the function `showSchedule` have inproper indentation.

Your `showSchedule` function should be:

```
void showSchedule(struct schedule *sch, unsigned long long num){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            printf("%c",(sch+i)->date[j]);
    
            if(j==3||j==5||j==7){
                printf(".");
            }
        }
        printf(" ");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
    
            printf("%c",(sch+i)->time[j]);
            
            if(j==1) printf(":");
        }
        printf(" %d ",(sch+i)->importance);
        printf("%s ",(sch+i)->name);
        printf("%s\n",(sch+i)->content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `(sch+i)->...` ok when `i` is `num-1`?

Comment: Also, its strange that `num` can be `long long int` but `i` is just an `int`, are we in danger of overflowing and causing UB?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox `(sch+i)->...` is OK when `i` is `num-1` because `sch` is a pointer to `num`-element array in this case. I agree that the combination of `unsigned long long num` and `int i;` is strange. Using `size_t` for both of them should be better. `%zu` should be used to read `size_t` value.